# Spinning earth svg using animate transform

Tags: html, svg, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate earth spin using SVG `<animateTransform>` attribute, following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vV8cej8w-k8).

It works fine, but when I apply it on my own SVG, I'm having trouble maintaining the earth map inside the circle, and I can't understand why since it's the same code as the tutorial and different width. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/rNxMJvw)

**Note**

Search for earth to find the relevant code.

Where did I go wrong when I applied it on my SVG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine but the `animateTransform` should be placed inside the `<clippath>` tag.

This is the code that is in the example you've mentioned
[image]

Updated your example in this pen https://codepen.io/jeffersonswartz/pen/vYLXREq